# How to print an array that was inputted from Scanner?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

So I have an array and trying to print what was input to the scanner. I'm trying to print the matrix that was input. Heres the code, what am I doing wrong here? I tried to print just graph, doesn't work.

```
/** Accept number of vertices **/
    System.out.println("Enter number of vertices\n");
    int V = input.nextInt();

    /** get graph **/
    System.out.println("\nEnter matrix\n");
    int[][] graph = new int[V][V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < V; j++)
            graph[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print(graph);
```

Comment: are you purposely trying to print the graph after each input from the user? or are you trying to print it out once when all the inputs have been received?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz He's just printing it at the end. Although the `System.out.println(graph);` is indented, it isn't part of the for loops because  the for loops have no curly braces.

Comment: oh ok, that's right. the indentation and no curly braces were messing with my head... thanks for the clarification @Asaph

Answer (score 0):

You can print the contents of an array using the [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) method but it doesn't work for multidimensional arrays, so for a 2 dimensional array, you'll need to loop through the elements in the first dimension. Like this:

```
for (int[] g : graph) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing arrays by simply passing it into `System.out.print` will print the array's hashcode. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4).

What you want to do is: `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(graph));`

`Arrays.toString(...)` will work for single dimensional arrays.

`Arrays.deepToString(...)` will work for more complex arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you try to print graph, you are actually printing a reference to an array object (If I am correct).

Also, for variables (like "V") you should use small caps

Instead of printing a graph, do this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < V; j++) {
                System.out.print(graph[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```